# Issues with Find/Replace of OLE Links

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm developing an Excel based template to link directly with a corresponding Powerpoint template and in the process discovered the change of MS's relative linking through defaulting to the parent directory (leaving linked files in the same folder meant they could be moved/copied/etc and links would update).

I've tried a handful of solves in Excel VBA and the only current working option includes saving the PPT as an XML file then doing a find/replace (PowerShell) of the old file paths with new ones constructed from variables passed in from the Excel file.

Sub ChangeOLELinks()

```
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim sOldPath As String
Dim sNewPath As String


sOldPath = "C:\__oldpath\oldfolder\old.xlsm"
sNewPath = "C:\__New Dangerous\Dangerous.xlsm"


For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
        ' Change only linked OLE objects
        If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ' Verify that file exists
            If Len(Dir$(Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, sOldPath, sNewPath))) > 0 Then
                 oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, sNewPath)
            End If
         End If
    Next    ' shape
Next    ' slide

MsgBox ("Done!")
```

The code above runs and does update links, but only some. My PPT contains both linked "grids" directly from worksheets and charts and for whatever reason the code below only updates the grids.

Even if there is a solve to get all shapes/OLEobjects to update, is there a way I can pass in variables from an Excel worksheet within the Powerpoint VBA?

Comment: since your code includes On Error GoTo errorHandler, I'd add the errorHandler label and code. I'm guessing that you've done that and just didn't include it in the code you pasted here, else this wouldn't compile or run. Also, before relinking to a file in a different location, the file must actually BE there. If not, PPT won't squawk, but it won't change the link.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - yes and thanks! Process wise this is the last step so the file will definitely be there, however PPT is still only linking up some of the links.

I'm half hoping for an "IDK" response since I'm a few lines away from getting a slick PowerShell script to update an .xml version of the PPT template and save as > new location\new name, but again figured the question here might help someone else.

Comment: A thought:  If it's only the charts that are not updating, as a test, open the presentation, select one of the charts and press the DEL key. Does the chart simply disappear, or does it leave a placeholder (ie, a "Click here to {whatever}" gadget) behind?  If so, there may be an easy fix.

Comment: It doesn't leave anything. For reference, I'm using PPT and Excel 2010.

...I'll also add that curly brackets in my default/template filename were wreaking havoc on my PowerShell script, so your comment does have me thinking. I rebuilt a PPT/folder path without any reserved characters so I might re-test my Macro with the new file. Thanks so much again for the response!

Comment: OK, the fact that it leaves nothing means that the chart was not in a placeholder; your code wouldn't touch anything within placeholders because they're a different object type.

Comment: Got it - good to know! I've suspected that placeholders were sort of their own beast, but in the off-chance I have the need for VBA in PPT in the future I'll have your watchout in pocket.

Answer (score 0):

While I've not been able to get this macro sufficiently working in PPT, I'm posting the solution I'm using instead. I've had success using find/replace in notepad when a PPT is saved as an XML (slide size updates w/o image stretching) so was able to replicate and automate the same process through PowerShell.

The only nuance is that I call the PowerShell script through the Excel file that I'm linking to PPT via VBA; reason being so I can pass in filepath/filename info from a worksheet and avoid the need for user inputs. Below is the PS script:

```
param(
[string]$ReplaceStr_1,
[string]$ReplaceStr_2,
[string]$ReplaceStr_3,
[string]$OUTPUTfilepath)

[string]$FindStr_1,
[string]$FindStr_2,
[string]$FindStr_3,

[String]$templatefile



$FindStr_1 = "C:\Reports%20Folder\template\NewReportTemplate001.xlsm"
$FindStr_2 = "C:\Reports Folder\template\NewReportTemplate001.xlsm"
$FindStr_3 = "[NewReportTemplate001.xlsm]"

$templatefile = "C:\Reports Folder\_MasterData\NewReportPresentation.xml"

Get-Content $templatefile | 
Foreach-Object { 
$_ -Replace [regex]::Escape($FindStr_1), $ReplaceStr_1 `
   -Replace [regex]::Escape($FindStr_2), $ReplaceStr_1`
   -Replace [regex]::Escape($FindStr_3), $ReplaceStr_3
} | Set-Content $OUTPUTfilepath
echo $OUTPUTfilepath

[Environment]::Exit(1)
```

For additional info, I'm using the CELL("filename",) function to generate my dynamic file paths to pass into the PS params above.

Below is the VBA macro for reference as well:

```
Sub BuildISLxmlPPT()
    Dim FR1 As String
    Dim FR2 As String
    Dim FR3 As String
    Dim psOUT As String

    FR1 = Range("xmlFR1").Value
    FR2 = Range("xmlFR2").Value
    FR3 = Range("xmlFR3").Value
    vbaOUT = Range("xmlOUT").Value

    strCommand = "Powershell -noprofile -File ""C:\Reports Folder\_MasterData\FindReplacePPTXML.ps1"" -psFR1 """ & FR1 & """ -psFR2 """ & FR2 & """ -psFR3 """ & FR3 & """ -OUTPUT """ & vbaOUT & """"

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.exec(strCommand)
    strOutput = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll

    MsgBox "New PPT.xml file generated here: " & strOutput, _
    Buttons:=vbInformation, _
    Title:="Perfection"
```

Comment: Also - note that my initial build had the filename(s) "{TEMPLATE}" for both the corresponding Excel and PPT files... this absolutely wreaked havoc on my PSscript (understandably). So if you're going to lift/shift this, note that reserved characters in your filenames/file path could trip things up. Thankfully my user base keeps filenames simple, unlike yours truly I suppose LOL